# How do you build and test the data layer of an Android app outside the emulator or Android tests?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to build and test the network and data layer of an Android app completely outside the Android environment. This would be the classes that make a network call to get JSON data and then convert the JSON objects to Java Objects.

To test this bit of code, I just want to write a program with a simple "main" function that can parse a few command line arguments, execute some code, and give some output.

How would I do that? I'm relatively new to Android and Java. I'm guessing the solution involves some tinkering with the Gradle build configuration.

After these components are tested, I'd like to incorporate them into a particular Android project. But before that I'd like to be able to develop these trickier bits of the code without all the baggage and clutter of the Android Studio and the Emulator, on the command line and a simple Vim editor.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own java project that use apache HttpClient and JSon(optional: Gson),
you can also use other tools like PostMan. Both for network test.

Comment: You can use Retrofit (a common, high-level REST library) instead of HttpClient. As far as I know, Retrofit doesn't have any dependencies on Android.

Comment: How can I keep these Java classes in the same Android Studio project file tree? I think this requires more knowledge of Gradle. If you can give me some pointers there I'll upvote.

Comment: I think it stays the same. Except library itself, in java project you can use jar file, in android project you can use gradle to import lib instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrapped the logic responsible for retrieving the remote JSON data in an android-independent class you could write a Junit test around it. For running this test you don't need to start the emulator (as soon as you don't embed any android logic within that class).

Answer (score 0):

(If these works for you, an upvote is highly appreciated. Thanks for your patience)

The way i understand this question is you want to save time required to learn android deveopment.

Here are some tricks that i use to save time in android development.

- Do not use any UI element except a simple activity with hello world screen ( which is default template in android when starting new project). In simple words No button, No Textbox. Practically no touch input at all.(When core of app is functional, do whatever you want).
- Set sample values directly in requests make to server (like set complete url directly in request).
- Output recieved data to console using System.out.println. Again No TextView, No ListView.
- Set your avd to lowest resource available. This make emulator very light but fully functional and quickly usable.

All these combined saves a lot time in development.

Comment: Sorry, this is not about learning Android development. It's about writing code in a modular way, and testing the complex modules separately.

Comment: @dan You are right. These are just a handful of methods that any beginner and casual android developer can use and apply.